# NSPredicate problem

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I'm attempting to search an array of objects using NSPredicate. The objects have a number of NSString properties that I want to filter.

I have the following code to do the filtering:

```
NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name like[c] %@",self.textFieldOutlet.text];
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
NSArray *results = [[MySingleton sharedMySingleton].cardArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
```

But I get the following error:

```
WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSUnknownKeyException> [<CardObject 0x14a530> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.
```

If I put single quotes around the `%@` it works but only if the entered text is exactly the same as the value held for the name key and not if it is 'like' the value. Thus not very useful. I must be doing something wrong with the predicate string, can anyone advise?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will you post the value to be stored in predicateString?

Comment: the error looks unrelated. Can you double check that the app works only when you insert single quotes?

Comment: Sorry about the delay folks. @iApple predicateString = name like[c] test.

Comment: @xj1200 I can confirm that the predicate will only return a value when I include single quotes. And it only returns something when the strings exactly match :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I still have no idea why I get a webview error for the NSPredicate. But I have fixed the issue using the following predicate string:

```
(name like[cd] '*%@*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error states that your object is not key-value compliant.
Try using NSDictionary instead

Answer (score 0):

The error states that your `CardObjects` don't support the property 'test' with KVO.

However, your predicate simply asks to compare the `name` property so it looks like this predicate isn't the reason that your webview is crashing.

Can you add the contents of your `webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction:` method to the question because that's where the bug is occurring.

I think that changing the predicate is changing the flow of the code later in this method, and that's where the error is (but without seeing the rest of your code, that's a bit of a guess!).

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for your answer. I only just noticed that the error had a webview in it, I've no idea why this is as the code is not called from a web view but instead just an ordinary view controller?! sorry for missing that, guess i've been staring at the same bit of code for too long!